# Where is the Java Google Gmail Api located?

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I know this may seem like a really stupid question, but I'm actually having a lot of trouble finding the Google Gmail API. I've searched all over Google's developer website, but all I get are downloads to the general google-api-client.

[image]

Those are the classes that I need, but when I try to import them with the standard google client api, it says the classes are missing.

[image]

That is what Google keeps telling me to download, the `google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev32-java-1.20.00` but in the libs folder there aren't any unique jars for the gmail api. In fact, all of the libs in this zip file are the same libs in the general api, which I've already used and can't find the classes I need.

I remember when I used the drive api for Google it was a pain to find the actual drive libraries, but I eventually found them. All I'm asking is where can I find the actually, gmail specific, libraries. A link would be helpful! Thanks! :D

Comment: You use the google-api-client to authorize your requests to Google APIs. If you're using Android (since you tagged Java), here's a quickstart guide: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Comment: Yes I understand that. I have the google-api-client, and I'm using it to authorize with OAuth2.0. What I want to know is where the gmail library is, for gmail specific api calls. Also, I'm not using Android for this project, just as a heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to resort to Maven to manage this for you. Even if you don't want to use Maven to manage dependencies directly, you can still use the repository to find your JAR files:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev32-1.20.0

And this is the direct download link, present on the website above:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev32-1.20.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev32-1.20.0.jar

Here is the link to the client API:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir, for saving me from hours of searching!